# Virtualenv consumes high CPU on lubuntu OS

Tags: python, virtualenv, cpu-usage

#### What I'm trying to do

Creating virtualenv with command

```
virtualenv -p python3.6 my_env_name
```

The env created successfully and runs, but the CPU usage goes above 80% and it stays there.

When I open the Task Manager I found Python3.6 has all the credits for the high consumption.

**Note**: This happens only on creation, so if I restarted my OS and activate the virtualenv everything is OK.

#### Things I tried to fix issue

- Deactivate the virtualenv (doesn't work)

The only worked two options

- Restart OS
- Kill python3.6 from the Task Manager

#### Demo for what is happening

The command

> virtualenv -p python3.6 myenv

Returned message

> created virtual environment CPython3.6.12.final.0-64 in 2214ms
> creator CPython3Posix(dest=/home/moh/Desktop/test_env/myenv, clear=False, global=False)
> seeder FromAppData(download=False, setuptools=bundle, wheel=bundle, pip=bundle, via=copy,
> app_data_dir=/home/moh/.local/share/virtualenv)
> added seed packages: pip==20.1.1, setuptools==47.3.1, wheel==0.34.2
> activators XonshActivator,PowerShellActivator,CShellActivator,FishActivator,BashActivator,PythonActivator

Screenshot of my CPU usage

[image: Lubunt CPU usage after create virtualenv]

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution on python documentation, [here](https://packaging.python.org/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtual-environments/#:%7E:text=To%20create%20a%20virtual%20environment,virtualenv%20in%20the%20below%20commands.&text=The%20second%20argument%20is%20the,project%20and%20call%20it%20env%20.)

Instead of:

```
virtualenv -p python3.6 myenv
```

Use:

```
python3.6 -m venv myenv
```

Kind Regards